Добраться до текущего соединения
Для реализации http-метода CONNECT мне надо переслать все дальнейшие данные этого соединения в другой сокет. Хотел прочитать из php://input, но там пусто, поскольку connect-запрос не имеет тела. Мне надо каким-то образом добраться до tcp-сокета текущего http-запроса и потоково читать данные из него. Как это сделать?
